# The new kernel causes system freeze

Tags: kernel, updates, freeze

I recently updated my netbook (Asus 1005px) running ubuntu 10.10. The update came with a newer kernel. And it causes the system to freeze. Randomly the screen goes off, and I have to do a force shutdown. I tried selecting older kernel in the grub menu and it works fine. Now I want to set the older kernel as default, or I want to get rid of the new kernel. What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Please don't forget to open a bug report for your problem with the newer kernel.

Comment: how to report a linux kernel bug -> https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/KernelTeamBugPolicies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot into the kernel you want to keep and run:

```
sudo aptitude hold linux-image-`uname -r` linux-image
```

You might have to remove the newer kernel version manually. You can see what's installed with this:

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image
```

And then

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-version-blah
```

Alternatively, you can do most of this by clicking around in Synaptic which might be a preferred option if you're not sure what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

i have same hardware and same problem. For me 2.6.36 maverick kernel fix the problem http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v2.6.36-maverick/

Comment: search keywords: 1005pe ubuntu 10 maverick freeze randomly. If that kernel version fix your problem, give me to know please

Answer (score 0):

I installed the native nvidia graphics driver, and it solved the same problem for me on Ubuntu 10.10 / 64 bits desktop (System / Administration / Additional drivers)